# É gerado um OPTIONS quando se realiza um POST

Tags: node.js, express.js

Tenho uma API e estou a tentar conectar com uma loja online mas todas as vezes que tento realizar um POST é retornado um OPTIONS. Decidi usar o JWT para autenticar os pedidos e evitar o OPTIONS mas sem sucesso.

```
app.post('/auth', function(req,res){
   var username = 114881;
   var token = jwt.sign(username, app.get('superSecret'), { expiresInMinutes: 60});
   res.send(token);
}
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> POST /auth 500 0.650 ms - 2086
>
> **Error:** "expiresInMinutes" is not allowed in "options"

Já tentei tudo o que se pode tentar mas tudo sem sucesso, com CORS, setHEADERS, etc...

Alguém já teve o mesmo problema?

Comment: O "verbo" em `OPTIONS` é gerado por causa do CORS. o CORS não é algo que vc coloca ou remove, o CORS é o [Controle de Acesso HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS), ele ocorre quando esta em uma URL e tenta acessar um dominio diferente, não tem como escapar disso, isso existe por segurança. JWt não tem nada haver com isto.

Comment: Caro amigo, se autenticar o POST com JWT deixamos de ter OPTIONS certo? É isso que estou a tentar fazer..

Comment: JWT não tem nada haver com OPTIONS, ou seja uma coisa não afeta a outra, o OPTIONS ocorre por causa do CORS e só por isto... O método HTTP OPTIONS é utilizado para que um cliente possa descobrir quais as opções de requisição permitidas para um determinado recurso em um servidor. O cliente pode especificar uma URL específica no método OPTIONS ou um asterisco(*) indicando que se refere ao servidor como um todo para sanar suas dúvidas em relação as opções de requisição permitidas. Ele ocorre justamente porque tua aplicação client-side faz tal checagem...

Comment: ... então você tem que criar uma rota no express com OPTIONS e nela definir as permissões via HEADER, PS: é possivel usar também esta rota para checar o JWt, claro que isto é opcional.